# Can anyone explain to me why this JavaScript Promise "pipeline" doesn't retain the array I push in...but the start index does?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

I apologize if this has been touched on before...but I haven't been able to find a question that gave me an answer...or perhaps if one existed that I ran across...it didn't click for me.

So, I originally had the following code that I was trying to use:

```js
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  nums.push(i * 5);

var nextPromise = Promise.resolve(0, nums);

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
  nextPromise = nextPromise.then((index, arr) => {
    console.log('index =>', index);
    console.log('nums[' + index + '] === ' +  arr[index]);
    return ++index;
  });
}
```

...but arr[index] would result in arr being undefined and I'd get an error...

```
(index):40 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Can anyone explain to me why arr becomes undefined? This was run in JsFiddle if that helps.

I did come up with one that works fine...but I didn't understand why piping the array through return values of each promise wasn't sufficient...the following code works fine...I just access nums on the inner scope which is still maintained from the outer scope:

```js
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  nums.push(i*5);

var nextPromise = Promise.resolve(0);

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  nextPromise = nextPromise.then(index => {
    console.log('index =>', index);
    console.log('nums[' + index + '] === ' +  nums[index]);
    return ++index;
  });
}
```

I'd love to know why arr becomes undefined...doesn't make sense to me since nums retains scope...but seemingly arr doesn't?

[Edit: After Answer Chosen]
So thanks to @Evert and further clarification from @Phil. I didn't realize resolve only used the first argument. With that information...the following code did the trick for anyone else that might have a problem. I still can't believe I wasn't realizing there was only the ++index return value...sigh.

The working code block:

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  nums.push(i * 5);

var nextPromise = Promise.resolve({index: 0, arr: nums});

for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
  nextPromise = nextPromise.then(params => {
    console.log('index =>', params.index);
    console.log('nums[' + params.index + '] === ' +  params.arr[params.index]);
    return {index: ++params.index, arr: params.arr};
  });
}
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#Parameters), a Promise may only resolve with a single value

Comment: @Phil I didn't realize it only used the first argument...knowing that I came up with a solution that works. I'm gonna edit it into the question for anyone else needing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your callback from `then()` returns a value, this value will be used as the first argument of the next `then()` function.

Only the first argument in your `then()` callback is used.

Comment: As I noticed that there was an answer I took another look...and realized I was only returning ++index...duh. I had one earlier than returned Promise.resolve(++index, arr)...but I don't think I had it wired correctly. Lol...figures. Thanks man.